# JQuery: Get jquery val on keypress from multiple ids with the same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, keypress

Hope anybody can help with this. 
I have a php foreach running, where I get multiple acticles from the database:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
   <div class="article">    
       <input id="comment" type="text"  class="materialize-textarea"  placeholder="Add comment"/>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Let's say i have 2 or more articles in the database. So on the html side the div gets duplicated and i have multiple divs with the same id.

Next i want jquery to get the input value. Here's the sample code

```
$("#comment").each(function()
{
            $(this).keypress(function(e) 
               {if (e.which == 13) 
                    alert('works');
                });
 });
```

The result: it works perfectly on the first record pulled from database(first article). on the second article and onward the JavaScript doesn't trigger at all. 
I understand the problem it's because jQuery reads the first div only. I check some solutions online, but nothing really worked for me. The most logical solution seemed to be putting .each in the function. But the result is the same. The first articles triggers JavaScript perfectly, the rest don't.

*Notes: If the php code looks strange please ignore it, it's on laravel framework. Nonetheless, it executes correctly.
The code presented here only shows the logic of the application and is not the actual code.*

Comment: `multiple divs with the same id` ***ID SHOULD ALWAYS BE UNIQUE*** use class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique, since it's using for uniquely identifying an element. The `id` selector only selects the first element which have the `id`, so use `class` instead for group of elements.

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
   <div class="article">          
       <input class="comment" type="text"  class="materialize-textarea"  placeholder="Add comment"/>
       <!-------^---- set class instead of `id` ---------------------------------------------------> 
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Then there is no need to iterate over them using **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**, just bind the **[`keypress()`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)** event handler directly to the selector.

```
$(".comment").keypress(function(e){
//-^-------- class selector
   if (e.which == 13) 
      alert('works');
});
```

Comment: Hmmm. That was easier than i thought. Thanks so much @Pranav. You saved me

Comment: @Shavkat : glad to help you :)

Comment: sorry another question. So to go further i assign the value of the input to a variable. it looks like this now $(".comment").keypress(function(e){
   if (e.which == 13)
       var content = $(".comment").val();
}); And the same thing is happening. It only assigns the value of the first articles. In the rest of them the value is empty

Comment: @Shavkat : you need to use `$(this).val()` , ` $(".comment").val();` gets value from the first element with that class

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
   <div class="article">    
       <input id="comment" type="text"  class="materialize-textarea commentArea"  placeholder="Add comment"/>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Javascript :

```
$(".commentArea").each(function(){
   $(this).keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
         alert("OK");
      }
   });
});
```

We can't use same IDs.Can use name or class.Using class is the best way.